# vuejs disable button depending array length

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to disable/enable a button depending of an array length and so, my code is the following:

```
  <button class="submit-button"
            type="button"
            v-on:click="DoSomething()"
            :disabled="array.length > 0">Submit</button>
```

Although, this doesn't work and as response I have the warning:

**array.length > 0 is not a valid value of attribute 'disabled'**

Is there any different syntax to enable/disable a button regarding an array length?

Any help is welcome

Comment: length starts from 1.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar good point but even though, the warning is the same

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar wow insightful comment :P

Comment: The problem is not in your code sample, using your code sample works fine.

Here is a Fiddle

`https://jsfiddle.net/koLjsux6/`
with your Code Sample.

Please include other relevant code for us.

Comment: @Badgy OP was using `>= 0` previously, so...

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Shouldn´t that be valid too or is my tired mind wrong?

Comment: `>0` is valid perfectly. I just tried to say why not just use .length. Ah, you mean `>=0`? NOT Valid. Will always be disabled.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar if i say ´3 >= 0` then it should bring me `true` because its bigger than 3, why should it be always disabled?

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Ahhh wait im dumb now I get what you mean, yes the length will always be greater than 0 but if you say it like that ´>` is as `NOT VALID` as `>=`

Comment: ah, you get it. but i'm sleepy so was not able to make  you clear. gn.

Comment: The mistake isn't related to your button element. I copy/pasted your code into a fresh vue app and it's working without errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/qlm75pj61q

Seems like the [v-bind directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) :disabled isn't receiving the value it's supposed to receive (true, false, null, undefined, defined...). You should print out the expression "array.length > 0" to see what it results in, the error must be located in there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Necropost!

but seriously, as the comments all point out, the code is perfectly fine, it is just that disabled is a negative, so you actually don't want to test for greater than zero, you want to test for zero if it is to be disabled

```
<button class="submit-button"
            type="button"
            v-on:click="DoSomething()"
            v-bind:disabled="myarray.length == 0">Submit</button>
```